# Numeros primos en javascript

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

He estado navegando por internet, pero no encuentro como realizar un algoritmo para buscar números primos.

```
var cantidad = 100,j=2;
for(var i=2;i<cantidad;i++) {      
    for(;j<cantidad;j++) {        
        if(j%i==0 && (i==j || i==1)) {          
            console.log(j);          
        }         
    }            
}
```

Intenté lo siguiente: Intentando desde 2, ya que los **números primos** comienzan desde ahí y en el condicional prácticamente me baso en que si el **residuo es 0**, y se cumple que el divisor es el mismo numero o 1, lo mostraría por consola, pero no funciona.

Entonces, Cuál es mi error y como debería ser?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466349/divisores-y-n%c3%bameros-primos/466779#466779

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Código

```js
var c = 100;
var j = 2;
var numerosPrimos = [];

for (; j < c; j++) {

  if (primo(j)) {
    numerosPrimos.push(j);
  }
  
}

console.log(numerosPrimos);

function primo(numero) {

  for (var i = 2; i < numero; i++) {

    if (numero % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }

  }

  return numero !== 1;
}
```

---

### Explicación

> Nota: Los números primos son aquellos que solo pueden ser divisibles por ellos mismos y por el numero uno.

Por lo tanto, hemos creado la funcion:

```
function primo(numero) {

  for (var i = 2; i < numero; i++) {

    if (numero % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }

  }

  return numero !== 1;
}
```

Que en lenguaje mas natural hace lo siguiente:

> Teniendo un `numero` iteramos desde 2 hasta el valor de `numero - 1` y en cada iteración verificamos si alguno de dichos números es divisible con `numero`, en caso que así sea, retornamos `FALSE` en caso contrario verificamos que el numero ingresado **no sea 1** ya que este no se considera un numero primo. Y si el numero evaluado no fue 1, entonces retornamos TRUE, sino retornamos FALSE.

Por lo tanto en este bucle:

```
for (; j < c; j++) {

  if (primo(j)) {
    numerosPrimos.push(j);
  }

}
```

Empezamos a recorrer cada uno de los numeros de la iteracion verificando a traves de la funcion `primo()` si el numero es primo y lo agrega al arreglo.

---

## Actualizacion

Debido a los comentarios que he visto, que parece que no te ha quedado claro como funciona este algoritmo procedo a explicartelo paso a paso.

#### Teniendo la siguiente función:

Ejecuta el Snippet para ver el funcionamiento paso a paso.

```js
function primo(numero) {

  console.log("Has pasado el numero: " + numero);
  console.log("Inicio bucle desde 2 hasta " + (numero - 1));

  for (var i = 2; i < numero; i++) {

    console.log("Modulo entre " + numero + " y " + i + " = " + (numero % i));

    if (numero % i === 0) {
      console.log(i + " es un multiplo de " + numero);
      console.log(numero + " no es un numero primo porque " + i + " es un multiplo");
      return false;
    }

  }

  if (numero === 1) {
    console.log("Me has pasado el numero 1, recuerda que NO es un numero primo");
  } else {
    console.log("Como el numero ingresado no tuvo mas múltiplos entonces determinamos que SI es un numero primo.");
  }

  console.log("-------------------------------------");
}

primo(2);
primo(4);
primo(5);
primo(10);
```

Comment: Si me lo explicas, podría entender por favor

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Por supuesto, eso estoy editando...

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Hecho!

Comment: No entiendo porque retornar false cuando su residuo es 0, porque si fuese así tampoco daria los primos, no? porque 5%5 == 0

Comment: Fijate que en el bucle evualuamos siempre y cuando sea menor al numero, o sea, si el numero es 5 se evalua hasta 4, ya que en ese caso el 5 siempre seria 0

Comment: Ya he hecho una aclaracion en la explicacion, espero te sirva, me puedes escribir cualquier duda

Comment: Se podría hacer más eficiente si en lugar de iterar hasta número - 1, se iterase hasta la raíz cuadrada del número

Comment: pero si retorna !== 1 retornaria igual false o no?, o que significa eso?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Mira bien el codigo, al final se evalua el valor de `numero`, *no se evalua el resultado de la operacion %*, lo que se hace en esa linea, es validar que el numero a evaluar no sea 1, ya que 1 no se considera como un numero primo

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No conocia esa opcion, tratare de hacer un ejemplo para el OP

Comment: esque no entiendo porque retas numero !== 1 , envez de retornar solo numero

Comment: @EduardoSebastian De nada serviria retornar numero, recuerda que hacer un retorno de un condicional devuelve el valor de esa condicion, TRUE o FALSE

Comment: @EduardoSebastian He hecho una modificacion a la explicacion, por favor leela.

Comment: @IvanBotero cualquier divisor mayor que la raíz cuadrada se tendría que multiplicar por un divisor menor que la raíz cuadrada para dar el número. Entonces si el número es primo, todos los números que compruebes desde sqrt(numero) hasta numero - 1 son innecesarios. No importa mucho en este intervalo porque es pequeño, pero si fuera más grande podría ahorrarse muchas operaciones.

Comment: Si en la funcion que chequea si es primo, si solo retorno true igual me funciona por eso no entiendo ya que si comienzas el ciclo for de 2, para que chequear si el numero es diferente de 1?

Comment: y aunque funciona, no entiendo porque funciona, osea si a la funcion primo le paso el numero 4, el ultimo numero que dividirá a 4 en el ciclo de la funcion será 3, entonces 4%3 , sí seria distinto de 0, ya que no es exacto y por ende no retornaria falso, y deberia considerarlo como primo, no?

Comment: Si quieres podriamos ir al chat

Comment: Y podriamos hacer una conversacion alli para que me expongas tu problema

Comment: @EduardoSebastian He agregado una actualizacion con una ejecucion paso a paso de la funcion, por favor revisalo, espero despeje tus dudas

Comment: Para qué vas a hacer el recorrido de los divisores de 1 en 1? Es muchisimo mas efectivo revisar los divisores que ya conoces que están en `numerosPrimos` (asumiendo que vas a hacer el recorrido de forma ascendente y no que vas a verificar si un número es primo a lo loco.... digamos verificar si el número 101 es primo sin haber recorrido los números menores que 101).

Comment: @eftshift0 No respondo por programas hechos hace mas de 3 años :D ya no soy activo en esta comunidad, si tienes una mejor solucion, publicala, todos somos bienvenidos

Answer (score 15):

El cálculo de números primos siempre ha sido un tema muy apasionante desde el punto de vista de la eficiencia, ya que entre algunas de las aplicaciones prácticas que requieren números primos muy grandes, se encuentra la criptografía. Uno de los algoritmos más usado en dicho campo es el algoritmo [RSA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA).

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea calcular la cantidad de números primos que existen en un rango de *N* números enteros positivos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

En tu aproximación de la solución tenemos el clásico condicional para determinar si un número es primo o no lo es:

```js
const elementos = 100;
const primos = [];
let iteraciones = 0;

for(let candidato = 2; candidato <= elementos; candidato++) {
    let primo = true;
    for(let divisor=2; divisor < candidato; divisor++) {
        iteraciones++;
        if(candidato%divisor === 0) {
            primo = !primo;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(primo) primos.push(candidato);
}

console.log(`iteraciones: ${iteraciones}`);
console.log(primos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Este algoritmo puede ser más eficiente. Si analizamos la parte en la que dividimos el candidato por el divisor, estamos haciendo una serie de divisiones adicionales innecesarias. Para este caso, con un valor de *N=100* tenemos un total de **1133 iteraciones!!!**

**Explicación**

Un [número compuesto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_compuesto) *n*, es cualquier número natural **no** primo, que puede ser escrito de la forma:

```
n = a * b; { con a y b distintos de 1 y además si a >= b  entonces b <= sqrt(n) y viceversa}
```

Esto significa que tanto *a*, como *b* (divisores de *n*) tienen un valor máximo que depende uno del otro.

Entonces, no es necesario iterar todos los valores desde *2* hasta *n* buscando los posibles divisores de *n*, basta con iterar hasta la raíz cuadrada de *n*. Y como la misma no será exacta en la mayoría de los casos, podemos prescindir de la parte decimal e iterar sólo hasta el entero más cercano por defecto.

La mejora del algoritmo anterior sería la siguiente:

```js
const elementos = 100;
const primos = [];
let iteraciones = 0;

for(let candidato = 2; candidato <= elementos; candidato++) {
    let primo = true;
    let maximoDivisor = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(candidato));
    for(let divisor=2; divisor <= maximoDivisor; divisor++) {
        iteraciones++;
        if(candidato%divisor == 0) {
            primo = !primo;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(primo) primos.push(candidato);
}
console.log(`iteraciones: ${iteraciones}`);
console.log(primos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Hemos reducido la cantidad de iteraciones a **236 iteraciones!!!** para obtener el mismo resultado. ¿Se podrá hacer aún más eficiente?.

**Criba de Eratóstenes**

En la [Criba de Eratóstenes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes), se pide escribir todos los números naturales desde 2 hasta *N*, luego, comenzando por 2, se recorre toda la lista marcando (tachando) todos los múltiplos de 2. Luego se hace lo mismo con el valor siguiente de la lista que no haya sido tachado (por ejemplo 3), y así se va avanzando hasta que hayamos tachado todos los números compuestos que hay entre 2 y *N*. Al final, los números que no hayan sido tachados en nuestra criba, serán precisamente los números primos que buscamos.

El algoritmo sería algo como esto:

1. Se crea una lista con todos los números de 2 a *N*.
2. Se itera desde *i=2* hasta *i <= Math.floor(Math.sqrt(N))* (por lo que vimos anteriormente)
3. Si *i* no ha sido tachado, se itera desde *j=i* hasta *Math.floor(N/i)* y se tacha cada múltiplo de *i* (*i*j*) en la lista.
4. Cuando se termina la iteración del paso 2, los números primos serán aquellos que no han sido tachados en la lista.

Un ejemplo (tomado de Wikipedia):

[image: Animación de la Criba de Eratóstenes]

Para implementar este algoritmo en Javascript, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

1. **Se crea una lista de elementos desde 2 hasta *N*:**

```js
const elementos = 100;
const criba = (new Array(elementos - 1)).fill(1);
```

En el código anterior, hemos creado un *Array* de 99 elementos (de 2 a *N* hay *N - 1* elementos), y este  *Array* lo hemos llenado con unos.

2. **Se itera desde *i=2* hasta *i<=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(N))*:**

```js
const maxDivisor = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(elementos));
for(let i = 2; i <= maxDivisor; i++) { ... }
```

En el código anterior se calcula la raíz cuadrada de *N* y se crea un bucle *for* que va desde 2 hasta dicho valor.

3. **Si *i* no ha sido tachado, se itera desde *j=i* hasta *Math.floor(N/i)* y se tacha cada múltiplo de *i* (*i*j*) en la lista.**

```js
//dentro del bucle for

// i representa el número que estamos probando, su posición en la lista es: i - 2
// si criba[i - 2] vale 1 significa que no ha sido tachado
if(criba[i - 2]) {
  //iteramos hasta Math.floor(elementos/i) ya que multiplicaremos i por j (múltiplos de i)
  //entre i y N hay N/i múltiplos
  for(let j = i; j <= Math.floor(elementos/i); j++){
    criba[(i*j) - 2] = 0; // recordar que debemos restar 2 para indicar el índice correcto
  }
}
```

En el código anterior, se tacha cada múltiplo del valor que se está iterando estableciendo su valor en la lista a cero.

4. **Cuando se termina la iteración del paso 2, los números primos serán aquellos que no han sido tachados en la lista.**

```js
const primos = [];

criba.forEach((primo, index) => {
  if(primo) primos.push(index + 2);
});
console.log(primos);
```

En el código anterior se crea un *Array* llamado *primos* y se recorre la criba. Por cada elemento no tachado (cuyo valor es 1) se guarda en el *Array* de primos su posición sumada con 2 (*index + 2*), que será el valor del primo.

Una implementación de este algoritmo podría ser:

```js
const elementos = 100;
const primos = [];
const criba = (new Array(elementos - 1)).fill(1);
let iteraciones = 0;

const maxDivisor = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(elementos));

for(let i = 2; i <= maxDivisor; i++) {
  if(criba[i - 2]) {
    for(let j = i; j <= Math.floor(elementos/i); j++){
      criba[(i*j) - 2] = 0;
      iteraciones++;
    }
  }
  iteraciones++;
}
criba.forEach((element, index) => {
  if(element) primos.push(index + 2);
});

console.log(`iteraciones: ${iteraciones}`);
console.log(primos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Notemos que este algoritmo es aún más eficiente que los dos anteriores, ya que, quitando el hecho de que debemos crear la lista de números y luego recorrer la misma para sacar los primos, se logra el resultado en tan solo **113 iteraciones!!!**.

Espero que esto deje clara las diferentes formas de lograr el objetivo, siendo la Criba de Eratóstenes una de las más eficientes.

**Usando un generador (ES6)**

Una posibilidad es utilizar un [generador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) para simplemente iterar sobre el mismo y que en cada iteración se devuelva el siguiente número primo de la secuencia.

La idea es sencilla y no se necesita almacenar los valores primos, lo que se hace es tomar la idea planteada en la criba de Eratóstenes y crear una estructura iterable que implemente el método [`next()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Generador/next), de tal forma que en cada llamada a dicho método se devuelva un valor primo y así podemos mostrar los primeros `n` enteros primos.

Lo primero es tener una forma de iterar los números naturales, dado un valor inicial. Podemos escribir una función generadora que devuelva la secuencia de números naturales (desde un valor n) cada vez que se llame a la función `next()` de la secuencia.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// generador de números naturales
const naturales = function* (inicio) {
  inicio = inicio < 1 ? (inicio === 0 ? 1 : -inicio) : inicio; // los naturales no son negativos
  
  yield inicio;
  yield* naturales(inicio + 1);
}

// creamos la secuencia que empiece en 1
const seq = naturales(1);

// mostramos los primeros 10 naturales:
for (let i = 0; i< 10; ++i) {
  console.log(seq.next().value);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Ahora necesitamos crear una función generadora que tome cada valor de la secuencia de números naturales y dado un primo, me devuelva todos los valores que no sean múltiplos de dicho primo. Esto es una criba sobre una secuencia de valores.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const criba = function* (seq, primo) {
  for (let num of seq) {
    if (num % primo !== 0) {
      yield num;
    }
  }
}
```

Esta función recorre una secuencia de números y devuelve aquellos que no sean múltiplos de `primo`.

Ahora que tenemos estas 2 funciones que devuelven una secuencia, podemos escribir otra función generadora que a partir de un valor inicial devuelva el siguiente valor primo. Esto lo logramos reescribiendo la secuencia de valores naturales por aquella que tenga los valores no múltiplos del primo anterior.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const primos = function* (seq) {
  let primo = seq.next().value;
  yield primo;
  seq = criba(seq, primo);
  yield* primos(seq);
}
```

En esta función se recibe una secuencia que (idealmente) inicia en un valor primo (supongamos el 2). Luego, por cada valor de la misma, crea una nueva secuencia que contiene sólo los números que no son múltiplos del primo generado, y devuelve dicho valor en cada llamado a `next()`.

Un ejemplo del código anterior funcionando para mostrar los primeros 10 primos sería:

```js
const naturales = function* (inicio) {
  inicio = inicio < 1 ? (inicio === 0 ? 1 : -inicio) : inicio; // los naturales no son negativos
  yield inicio;
  yield* naturales(inicio + 1);
}

const criba = function* (seq, primo) {
  for (let num of seq) {
    if (num % primo !== 0) {
        yield num;
    }
  }
}

const primos = function* (seq) {
  let primo = seq.next().value;
  yield primo;
  seq = criba(seq, primo);
  yield* primos(seq);
}

const p = primos(naturales(2));

// mostrar los primeros 10 valores primos
for(let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  console.log(p.next().value);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Si bien este algoritmo tal vez no sea tan eficiente como los presentados con anterioridad, es otra forma de obtener valores primos usando generadores de Javascript para obtener una secuencia que siempre devolverá un valor primo cada vez que se llame al método `next()`.

Comment: Muy ilustrativo. Sería bueno destacar que no es necesario iterar los tests de divisibilidad más allá de la raíz cuadrada del número, para aquellos que necesitan establecer si un número dado es o no primo.

Comment: @quevedo, ¿en qué momento eso no queda claro en la respuesta? XD

Comment: Si queda claro. Pero es un detalle que merece ser destacado.

Comment: Gran explicación. +1

Comment: La afirmación "Solo será necesario realizar el test de divisibilidad hasta la raíz cuadrada" no es cierta, sin ir más lejos, la raiz cuadrada de 14 es menor que su factor primo 7.

Comment: Pero es mayor que su factor primo 2, y a eso se refiere el test de divisibilidad. @EduardoSebastian

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Sí, la raiz cuadrada de 14 es 3.74, pero basta buscar divisores hasta 3.74, pues entre ellos encontrarás el 2 y al dividir 14 entre 2, ya te sale el otro factor 7. Fijate que no se trata de encontrar los factores, solo de ver que no es primo. Si no aparece ningun divisor por debajo de raiz de 14 tampoco aparecerá ya por encima.

Comment: Muy, pero muy útil explicación y respuesta. Una de las mejores con las que me he topado.

Answer (score 3):

1. Eratosthenes algorithm encontrar todos los numeros debajo de n
2. iniciamos un array para todos los numeros en true
3. eliminamos del array los multiplos
4. agregamos a otro array los que no tienen multiplos

```js
function eratosthenes(n) {
  var array = [],
    upperLimit = Math.sqrt(n), //(1)
    output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) { //(2)
    array.push(true);
  }

  for (var i = 2; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
    if (array[i]) {
      for (var j = i * i; j < n; j += i) {
        array[j] = false; //(3)
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (array[i]) {
      output.push(i); //(4)
    }
  }
  return output;
};
console.log(eratosthenes(30))
```

Tambien existe este algoritmo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin es moderno para hallar los numeros primos

Answer (score 2):

Te quedaria mejor  sabiendo que los numeros a pares excepcion del 2 no es primo , los sacamos de la formula; nos restarian sacar los numeros impares que podrian ser 3 ,5 , 7 ,9 pero sabemos que 9 es multiplo de 3 y lo emitimos, solo nos quedarian 3 , 5 y 7 , como ya sabemos los numeros del 1 al 10 cuales son los primos los podemos omitir y empezar desde el 11 sumando de dos en dos y asi no tenemos que validar si es par

```js
var cantidad = 100,j=2;

function espar( x ) {
  return !( x & 1 );
}
function esMultiplo( x , multiplo ) {
  return (x % multiplo) == 0;
}

for(var i=11;i<cantidad;i+=2) {
    if (esMultiplo(i , 3) || esMultiplo(i , 5) || esMultiplo(i , 7)){
      continue;
   }
  console.log(i)         
}
```

De esta forma solo usa un for, recorre menos numeros del 11 hasta el 100 y los resultados son los deseados

Answer (score 2):

Bueno yo me base en esta formula,  Lo saque de la pagina: http://www.ceiploreto.es/sugerencias/ceibal/Primo_o_compuesto/cmo_saber_si_un_nmero_es_primo.html!

[image]

Use la consola para apreciar el resultado.
Lo que hice fue crear dos funciones:
La primera se encarga de evaluar si es o no es un numero primo.
Y la segunda se encarga de que numero a que numero deseas saber los números primos.

```
 /* Esta primera función es la encargada de saber si el
numero ingresado es un numero primo; si en caso es primo
devuelve el numero y en caso que no lo es no devuelve
nada*/

const puederSerPrimo = (numero = undefined) => {

  /*Lo que hago aquí es que 0 y 1 decir que no son
  números primos, ya que al mandar un return sin nada
  entonces no estaríamos enviando ningún valor.*/

  if (numero === 0) return
  if (numero === 1) return
  /*El return vacío no enviara nada al array*/

  /* Lo que hice aquí fue colocar las bases de los
  números primos */
  let basesDePrimos = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

  /* Con la ayuda de un for reviso si el numero
  ingresado es igual que alguna base de los primos */
  for (let z = 0; z <= basesDePrimos.length; z++) {
    while (numero === basesDePrimos[z]) {
      return console.log(`El ${numero} si es primo.`)
    }
  }

  /* Lo que hice aquí declarar una una variable
  divisiones para así con la ayuda de un while
  controlar el  numero de las divisiones */
  let divisiones = 0

  /* El numero de divisiones no puede ser mayor que la
  cantidad de números de las bases de los primos*/
  while (divisiones < basesDePrimos.length) {

    /* El for hace que avance 1 por 1 de casilla de el
    Array basesDePrimos*/
    for (let n = 0; n <= basesDePrimos.length; n++) {

      /* El signo % saca el residuo de una división y
      si en caso el residuo es 0, significa que no es
      un numero primo */
      let residuo = numero % basesDePrimos[n]

      while (residuo === 0) {
        return
        /*El return vacío no enviara nada al array*/
      }
    }

    /* Con divisiones++ hago que incremente el valor de
    divisiones dentro del while ya que si no
    incrementamos el valor haremos un bucle infinito*/
    divisiones++
  }

  /* Por ende si el numero al dividirse con las bases
  de los primos no obtuvo un residuo de 0, sacamos la
  conclusión que es un numero primo*/
  return console.log(`El ${numero} si es primo.`)

}

/* Esta función se encarga de saber de que numero a que
numero deseamos saber los números primos; también llama
a la función anterior y con la ayuda del for recorremos
1 por 1 los números*/
const numeroDePrimos = (inicio, final) => {
  for (let v = inicio; v <= final; v++) {

    /* Con la ayuda de un Array vacío y el push imprimo
    en la consola los numero primos encontrados*/
    let primos = []
    primos.push(puederSerPrimo(v))

  }
}

/* Aquí declaro el inicio y el final de todos los
numero que deseo saber si son primos*/
numeroDePrimos(0, 100);
```

Aquí la misma respuesta pero sin comentarios

```
  const puederSerPrimo = (numero = undefined) => {

  if (numero === 0) return
  if (numero === 1) return

  let basesDePrimos = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

  for (let z = 0; z <= basesDePrimos.length; z++) {
    while (numero === basesDePrimos[z]) {
      return console.log(`El ${numero} si es primo.`)
    }
  }

  let divisiones = 0

  while (divisiones < basesDePrimos.length) {

    for (let n = 0; n <= basesDePrimos.length; n++) {

      let residuo = numero % basesDePrimos[n]

      while (residuo === 0) {
        return
      }
    }

    divisiones++
  }

  return console.log(`El ${numero} si es primo.`)

}

const numeroDePrimos = (inicio, final) => {
  for (let v = inicio; v <= final; v++) {

    let primos = []
    primos.push(puederSerPrimo(v))

  }
}

numeroDePrimos(0, 100);
```

Y si en caso quisieras imprimir en la consola todos los números de inicio a fin y aparezca si es o no es un numero primo entonces:

```
 const puederSerPrimo = (numero = undefined) => {
  if (numero === undefined) return console.warn(`No se 
  puede dejar vacio`)
  if (numero === 0) return console.log(`El numero 
  ${numero} no es primo.`)
  if (numero === 1) return console.log(`El numero 
  ${numero} no es primo.`)
  if (!numero) return console.error(`No se puede
  colocar texto`)

  let basesDePrimos = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

  for (let z = 0; z <= basesDePrimos.length; z++) {
    while (numero === basesDePrimos[z]) {
      return console.log(`El ${numero} si es primo.`)
    }
  }

  divisiones = 0

  while (divisiones < 6) {

    for (let n = 0; n <= basesDePrimos.length; n++) {

      let residuo = numero % basesDePrimos[n]

      while (residuo === 0) {
        return console.log(`El ${numero} no es primo.`)
      }
    }
    divisiones++
  }

  return console.log(`El ${numero} si es primo.`)

}

const numeroDePrimos = (inicio, final) => {
  for (let v = inicio; v <= final; v++) {
    let primos = []
    primos.push(puederSerPrimo(v))

  }
}

numeroDePrimos(0, 100);
```

solo agrego a los return vacíos un console.log con un Templai String agregar los valores y también agredo dos if al inicio. Espero que te haya sido útil. Saludos !!!

Answer (score 1):

Para calcular los semiprimos de un numero a, a un numero b

```
function findSemiprimes(rangeStart, rangeEnd) {
  let inicio = rangeStart
  let final = rangeEnd
  // configuramos el inicio 
  if (final < inicio) {
    inicio = rangeEnd
    final = rangeStart
  }

  // calculamos los primos dentro del rango
  let primos = []
  for (let i = 1; i <= final; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      primos.push(i)
    }
  }

  let semiPrimos = []

  for (const primo of primos) {
    let primos2 = []
    for (let i = 2; i <= primo; i++) {
      if (isPrime(i)) primos2.push(i)
    }
    for (const primo2 of primos2) {
      let posible = primo * primo2
      if (posible <= final) {
        if (semiPrimos.indexOf(posible) <= 0) {
          semiPrimos.push(posible)
        }
      }
    }

  }

  semiPrimos.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  })
  semiPrimos = semiPrimos.filter(primo => primo >= inicio)
  return semiPrimos
}


function isPrime(num) {
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return num !== 1;
}

function main() {
  const result = findSemiprimes(20, 100);
  console.log("result:", result)
}

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí os muestro mi función en JavaScript de comprobación de números primos simplificada y optimizada y comentada...

```
function esNumeroPrimo(Numero){
    // Método Abreviado de Comprobación de Números Primos
    var Retorno = true;
    var x = 0;
    // Aquí convertimos el dato que recibimos de la función en entero
    Numero = parseInt(Numero);
    // Si no es un dato entero es que no es primo
    if (Number.isInteger(Numero) == true){
        // Si el número es 0 1 o 4 es que no es primo
        if (Numero == 0 || Numero == 1 || Numero == 4) { 
            Retorno = false; 
        }else{
            // Si el número es mayor o igual a 4 seguimos comprobando y si no es primo
            if (Numero >= 4){
                // Aqui primero descartamos cualquier número par
                if (Numero % 2 == 0) { Retorno = false; }
                // Si era par salimos, si no seguimos   
                if (Retorno == true ){
                    // Ahora comprobamos todos los impares hasta la mitad del número  
                    for ( x = 3; x < Numero / 2; x = x + 2) {
                        if (Numero % x == 0) { Retorno = false; break; }
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
    }else{
        Retorno = false;
    }
    // Y así retornamos un valor true si era primo y si no un valor false   
    return Retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rango = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un rango"));
var contador = 0;
const primos = [];
while(contador<=rango){
    var primo = contador;
    if (typeof primo== "number"){
        var ceros = 0;
        for(var i=1; i<=primo; i++){
            if(primo%i==0){
                ceros++;
            }
        }
        if(primo==0 || primo==1){
            primos[i]=null
        }
        else if(ceros==2){
            primos[i]=primo;
        }
    }else{
        alert("Numero incorrecto")
    }
    contador++;
}
// var cadena = primos.toString();
// var a = cadena.replace(/,/g, "")
// var n_Primos = a.length;
document.write(primos);
```

Comment: Un código sin explicación alguna no es una respuesta muy correcta. Por favor, añade comentarios y/o explicaciones para que cumpla con lo que debe ser una buena respuesta. Para más info puedes leer [answer]

Answer (score -1):

```
      function primo(n){
    if( n <=1 || n ==2){
        return('es numero primo ') 
} else{
    for(let i = 2; i <= n; i++){
        if(n%i===0){
            return ('No es primo')
        }else{
            return('Es primo')
        }
    }
}
}

console.log(primo(13))
```

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] y explicá brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Fijate cómo casi todas las demás respuestas son completas y bien explicadas. Leé [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
function esPrimo(n) {
  let i = 1;
  while (n % ++i != 0);
  return n == i;
}

for (let i = 2; i < 100; i++)
  if (esPrimo(i))
    console.log(i);
```

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, bienvenido a SOes. Te animo a leer [answer] y a hacer el [tour] para conocer el sitio. Tu respuesta es correcta pero no has dado ninguna explicación de cómo funciona. Para que sea mejor valorada es conveniente explicar lo máximo posible tu solución.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución Juan pero es recomendable agregar una explicación del código, este tipo de respuestas no son bien recibidas por la comunidad, saludos.