# Optimizar función para determinar si un numero es primo Javascript

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, matemáticas, números-primos

Estaba haciendo la función para determinar si un numero es primo o no en una pagina de problemas. probé varias soluciones pero mis funciones no pasaban el test de velocidad. probé con una función mas optimizada del usuario [Mauricio Contreras](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/390235/mauricio-contreras) pero tampoco paso el test de velocidad.

```js
function isPrime(n) {
    let primos = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29];
    if(n<2){
        return false
    }
    else if(primos.indexOf(n) > -1){
        return true;
    }else if(primos.some((primo) => (n%primo == 0))){
        return false;
    }else{
        if(n <= primos[primos.length-1]*2){
            return true;
        }else{
            let test = true;
            for(let i= primos[primos.length-1]+1; i<= Math.floor(n/2); i++){
                if(n %i==0){
                    test=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return test;
        }
    }
}

console.log(isPrime(3));
console.log(isPrime(73));
console.log(isPrime(24));
console.log(isPrime(5099));
```

después de bastantes intentos con esta función pase el test de velocidad:

```js
function isPrime(numero)
{
    let primo = true;
    if(numero<2)
    {
        primo = false;
    }
    else
    {
        for(let x=2; x*x<=numero; x++)
        {
            if( numero%x==0 ){
                primo = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return primo;
}

console.log(isPrime(3));
console.log(isPrime(73));
console.log(isPrime(24));
console.log(isPrime(5099));
```

mi pregunta es *¿Se puede optimizar mas la esta función para determinar si un numero es primo o no?*

Comment: No existe función matemática ni de programación para determinar si un número es primo que sea óptimo.

Comment: las formulas ya las eh visto, las busque es como tu dices las hay que sirven hasta un numero n no me interesa calcularlos hasta el infinito pq tampoco podre con una funcion de javascript...estoy preguntando por el algoritmo mas rapido q funcione al menos para los enteros de javascript @jacknavasparrow

Comment: si bien lo que dice Kleith es cierto, se puede reducir el universo porque solo es necesario testear hasta la raiz cuadrada del número.

Comment: Y puestos a optimizar, a parte de lo que bien dice @Emeeus, no calcules la raíz cuadrada en la condición del for, ya que así haces esa operación en cada iteración. Calcula la raíz cuadrada antes de empezar el for y usa ese valor como condición de parada

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Numeros primos en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98287/numeros-primos-en-javascript)

Comment: Parece una tontería pero hay que decirlo, la forma mas óptima es en realidad comparar el número en cuestión con una lista de números primos pre calculada, y esas listas existen hasta números muy altos, aquí por ejemplo: https://www.bigprimes.net/archive/prime/20000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya han indicado, no existe de momento una formula directa que indique si un número es primo o no (es uno de los problemas mas grandes de la historia).

La forma mas optima conocida es comprobar si el numero no es divisible por los números primos menores o iguales a la raíz cuadrada del número.

Si lo que buscas es una función mas optima y ademas que se reduzca significativamente la cantidad de lineas de código puedes optar por la siguiente solución:

```js
getprimes = (n, p = [2], i = 3) =>
    n>=i ? getprimes(n, p.reduce((ac, el) => ac && i % el) ? [...p,i] : p, i+=2) : p

isprime = (n) => {
  primes = getprimes(Math.sqrt(n)|0);
  return primes.reduce((ac, el) => ac && n % el) != 0
}

console.log(isprime(3));
console.log(isprime(73));
console.log(isprime(24));
console.log(isprime(5099));
console.log(isprime(1999));
console.log(isprime(5781));
console.log(isprime(19999));
console.log(isprime(199999));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

La primera función `getprimes()` es una función recursiva que devuelve un array con los números primos hasta **n**.

La función `isprime()` obtiene los números primos menores o iguales a la raíz cuadrada de **n**, luego verifica si no es divisible por todos los números del *array*.

Si el resultado es 0 implica que **n** fue dividido por algún numero del array dando como resto 0.

Si es distinto de 0, hubo residuo mayor a 0 al dividir **n** con todos los números del *array*.

Aunque debo agregar que si lo que se busca es mejor rendimiento, es mas recomendable emplear un bucle en lugar de recursividad.

Para eso se puede optimizar la función mostrada en la pregunta de la siguiente forma:

```js
function isPrime(numero){
    if(numero<2||(numero%2==0&&numero!=2))
       return false;
    for(let x=3; x*x<=numero; x+=2)
       if( numero%x==0 )
          return false;
    return true;
}

    console.log(isPrime(2));
    console.log(isPrime(73));
    console.log(isPrime(24));
    console.log(isPrime(5099));
    console.log(isPrime(1999));
    console.log(isPrime(5781));
    console.log(isPrime(19999));
    console.log(isPrime(199999));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

En esta mejora ademas de evitar los números menores a 2, se verifica que el numero no sea par, ningún numero par es primo excepto 2.

```
if(numero<2||(numero%2==0&&numero!=2))
       return false;
```

luego en el bucle se puede empezar a verificar a partir de 3 y solo por números impares, ya que ya se restringieron números pares con el anterior `ìf`, de ese modo se reducen a la mitad la cantidad de iteraciones.

```
for(let x=3; x*x<=numero; x+=2)
    if( numero%x==0 )
        return false;
```

De esa forma se puede hacer aun mas optima la función.

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.