# NÚMEROS PRIMOS EN JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

alguien podría ayudarme con a arreglar mi código, estoy tratando de obtener todos los números primos del 1 al 100, pero estoy teniendo problemas. Es en Javascript.

```
 var c = 0;

var primos = [];


for(var i = 1; i<=100;i++){
    for(let j=1;j<=i;j++){
        if(i%j===0){
            c++;

        }
        if(c == 2){
            primos.push(i);
        }

    }

}

console.log(primos);
```

Comment: Creo que esto es para ti https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98287/numeros-primos-en-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba poniendo el `if` fuera del primer `for`

```
let primos = []

for(let i=2; i<=100; i++) {
    for(let j=2; j<=i; j++) {
        if (i % j === 0) {
            c++;
        }
    }
    if (c == 2){
       primos.push(i);

    }
    c=0;
}
```

Al sacarlo fuera lo que hace es esperar a comprobar todo el rango de números.
De la otra forma lo que hacías, es que con cada cuenta hiciese la comprobación de número primero, por lo que se habría muchos primos incorrectos.

El `c= 0` hay que ponerlo por que al terminar el ciclo con un número que estas comprobando tienes que resetar esta cuenta para que no se arrastre a las siguientes comprobraciones

Podemos simplificar y hacer más eficiente el código de esta manera.

```
let primos = [];
for(var i = 2; i<=100; i++) {    
    let j = 2;
    for(; j<i && (i % j !== 0); j++);
    if (j === i){
       primos.push(i);
    }
}
```

En el segundo `for` la sentencia: `j<i && (i % j !== 0)` lo que hace es el que bucle pare una vez encuentre un número que por el cual sea divisible por tanto deje de ser primo.

Comment: Por favor, no copies y pegues el código sin dar ninguna explicación de lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: Hola @magalin. Ell `1` no es un **número primo**. Recuerda que los números primos son aquellos que son únicamente divisibles por 1 y por si mismo; es decir, tiene dos (02) divisores. Puedes consultar en la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_primo) qué son los números primos. Pulse editar e inicialice el array `primos` en `2` en lugar de `1`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!.