# Como podria sumar solo los numeros primos de un array?

Tags: javascript, array, números-primos

Buenas a todo quisiera saber como podria sumar lo numero primos de este array y que me de el resultado de dicha suma,(pero solo de los numeros primos)
Tomando en cuenta que el array se va a recibir como parametro pero de igual manera me dieron un ejemplo para probar que funciona "[1, 5, 2, 9, 3, 4, 11] devuelve 21" Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?, por favor edita y agrega

Comment: Aqui ya tienes todo bueno el 99 por cierto del trabajo hecho: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98287/numeros-primos-en-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) de los arreglos y aplicar la evaluación de números primos para saber si hay que sumarlos o continuar. La función reduce nos permitirá llevar la suma en la iteración de todo el arreglo.

Te dejo el siguiente código:

```js
/**
 * Dado un número, nos indíca si es primo o no.
 * @param {Number} numero Número a evaluar 
 * @returns {Boolean} Resultado de la evaluación
 */
const esNumeroPrimo = (numero) => {
  let divisores = 0;
  for (let i = 2; i < numero; i++) {
    if (numero % i === 0) {
      divisores++;
    }
  }
  return numero > 1 && divisores === 0;
};

/**
 * Dada una colección de números, retorna la suma de todos los números primos.
 * @param {Array<Number>} numeros Coleción de números a sumar 
 * @returns {Number} Suma de números primos
 */
const sumarNumerosPrimos = (numeros) => {
  return numeros.reduce((anterior, actual) => esNumeroPrimo(actual) ? anterior + actual : anterior,0);
}

const numeros = [1, 5, 2, 9, 3, 4, 11];

console.log('La suma de los números primos es: ' + sumarNumerosPrimos(numeros));
```

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias de verdad, Era para un examen y me la pase ayer hasta las 1am tratando de encontrar la solución por mi cuenta! de verdad te lo agradezco ya comprendí que pasos estaba haciendo mal! MUCHAS GRACIAS!!

Comment: De nada! Recuerda votar la respuesta si te ayudo.