# sumar número primos en javascript

Tags: javascript

cordial saludo, se que para muchos será fácil y abran miles de formas, yo recien comienzo. Se me pidió crear una función que encuentre los números primos y después los sume.  Como verán lo dividi en dos partes una encontrar los primos y otra sumarlos, por ende hay dos ciclos "for" cada uno con su condicionantes, sin embargo no me ejecuta la función espero no sea de mucha molestia decirme que hice mal puesto que uní los dos ciclos, creo que hay una variable que no estoy guardando, en fin de verdad quedo agradecido por la guia. . Muchas gracias.

````
function sumaTodosPrimos(array) {
  // La funcion llamada 'sumaTodosPrimos' recibe como argumento un array de enteros.
  // y debe devolver la suma total entre todos los numeros que sean primos.


if( array < 2) return false;
  if(array === 2) return true;
  for(var i = 2; i < array; i++) {
    if(array % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;


var suma = 0;
if (array === true) {

 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)

    {suma = suma + array[i];  }
 
}
  
 return suma;

}```
````

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Numeros primos en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98287/numeros-primos-en-javascript)

Comment: Para responder a tu pregunta, hace falta saber que rango de primos quieres sumar, ya que "todos" son miles de millones de números conocidos.

Answer (score -1):

Espero esto sea lo que buscas.

```js
function sumaTodosPrimos(array) {
    // La funcion llamada 'sumaTodosPrimos' recibe como argumento un array de enteros.
    // y debe devolver la suma total entre todos los numeros que sean primos.


    // if (array < 2) return false;
    // if (array === 2) return true;
    var arrayEnteros = []; //Inicializo un array donde metere todos los primos
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {//Accedemos a la posicion 0 del array y recorremos cada item con array.length
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) { // Validamos si es primo, por que su resto debe ser 0
            arrayEnteros.push(array[i]); //Agrego el item al array
        }
    }
    // return true;

    var suma = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayEnteros.length; i++) {//Recorro mi item de primos
        suma = suma + arrayEnteros[i]; //hago mi sumatoria
    }

    return suma;//regreso todas las sumas

}
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].append(`Suma de todos Primos: ${sumaTodosPrimos([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])}`)
```

Documente cada paso, para indicar mejor que hace.

Comment: Pide sumar los números **primos**, NO los números pares. En el array que declaras `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` primos solo son 2, 3 y 5 por lo que la suma debe ser 10, no 12.