# Divisores y números primos

Tags: javascript, funciones, algoritmos

soy nueva en javascript y hoy en clases nos dieron este ejercicio y no pude resolverlo, sinceramente no se ni por donde empezar. Me podrían orientar en como podría hacerlo. Ahora adjunto el problema.
Intente con un for iniciando en 2 y sacando el modulo de i pero no se que hacer.
Ahí pase el código, pero el problema es que no muestra "Es primo"

```
function divisores(numero) {
  // La funcion llamada 'divisores' recibe como argumento un numero (entero) 
  // y debe devolver un array con los divisores exactos de 'numero'.
  // Si el numero no tiene divisores ( exeptuando el 1 y el mismo ) deberia devolver el string 'Es primo'
  // Nota: El array no debe contener el 1 y el mismo numero.
  // Por ej:
  // divisores(15) devuelve [3, 5]
  // divisores(11) devuelve 'Es primo'
  // Tu código aca:
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 2; i < numero; i++) {
    let res = numero % i;
    if(res === 0)   {
      result.push(i);
    }
  }
  if(result.count === 0) {
    return 'Es primo';
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Comienza revisando la definición que tienes ahí de número primo, luego define un proceso sin código por el cual podría identificarse el conjunto de divisores de un número y luego intenta codificar ese proceso.

Comment: @Marcos ahí lo edite pero ese es el problema

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Numeros primos en javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98287/numeros-primos-en-javascript)

Comment: Sólo como pequeña anotación: Regresar 2 tipos de datos diferentes en una función puede ser un poco confuso y requiere de más código por parte de quienes usen la función. Aunado a esto, los motores de JS y su optimización JIT compilation pueden no optimizar la función pues éstos prefieren optimizar funciones que retornen el mismo tipo de dato siempre.

Answer (score 2):

Ya vi cual es tu problema, no debes usar count para saber la cantidad de elementos de tu arreglo. En este caso debes usar length. Tu código quedaría así

```
function divisores(numero) {
  // La funcion llamada 'divisores' recibe como argumento un numero (entero) 
  // y debe devolver un array con los divisores exactos de 'numero'.
  // Si el numero no tiene divisores ( exeptuando el 1 y el mismo ) deberia devolver el string 'Es primo'
  // Nota: El array no debe contener el 1 y el mismo numero.
  // Por ej:
  // divisores(15) devuelve [3, 5]
  // divisores(11) devuelve 'Es primo'
  // Tu código aca:
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 2; i < numero; i++) {
    let res = numero % i;
    if(res === 0)   {
      result.push(i);
    }
  }
  if(result.length === 0) {
    return 'Es primo';
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Por cierto, solo hace falta hacer el bucle hasta la mitad de "numero" (entero)  ya que es la última opción. Por ejemplo 10 como máximo es divisible por 5.

Comment: No necesariamente hasta mitad, porque número pudiera ser impar.

Comment: Por esto he puesto (entero), si se busca el 11, solo hace falta mirar hasta el 5.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta a tu problema, es el explicado por @Jean-Gotopo, cuando tengas un momento marca su respuesta como la correcta.

Por mi parte, quisiera explicar un par de detalles a la hora de buscar números primos, por si te es de ayuda.
Lo importante es tener claro que:

- El **único** primo par, es el 2.
- Un número como máximo es divisible por su mitad (sin decimales), y en ese caso seria par.

De esto podemos deducir que:

- Solo es necesario comprobar los dividendos impares, exceptuando el 2.
- Solo es necesario comprobar los divisores impares, inferiores a la mitad entera del número buscado.

Así que poniendo en práctica esa información podemos hacer una función parecida a esta:

```js
function esPrimo(numero) {
      var resultado;
      if (numero == 2 || numero == 3 ) resultado = true; // El único primo par, y si coincide con el primer divisor.
      else if (!(numero%2)) resultado = false; // Desecha el resto de pares.
      else {  // Comprueva solo divisores impares a partir del 3,
              // mientras sean inferiores a la mitad entera...
              // ... y no sean divisores del numero, al primero que encuentre, sale. 
        for (var i = 3; !!(numero%i) && i < Math.floor(numero/2); i+=2);
        resultado = !!(numero%i); // El resultado serà si el divisor actual no lo es del numero.
      }
      return resultado;
}
    
for (let n=2 ; n<100 ; n++){
      if (esPrimo(n)) console.log(n); // Puesta la lista de primos hasta el 99
}
```

Y adaptando el código a lo que te piden, se parecería a:

```js
function esPrimo(numero) {
      var resultado=[];
      for (let i = 2; i <= Math.floor(numero/2); i++){
        if (!(numero%i)) resultado.push(i);
      }
      if (!resultado.length) resultado="Es primo";
      return resultado;
    }

for (let n=2 ; n<20 ; n++){
      console.log(n,esPrimo(n));
}
```

EDIT:
Como bien dice @mateo, la búsqueda de divisores se puede limitar hasta la raiz entera del número a comprobar.
Una explicación podría ser la siguiente:
Si tenemos que n=a*b, como el orden de los factores no altera el producto, podemos ordenar los factores de manera que a<=b

Así que 'a' como máximo valdrá 'b' y en ese caso tendríamos que a=b entonces n=b*b así que b=raíz de n.
Así que no hace falta buscar mas allá de raíz de n, ya que un factor > b obtendría un producto > n.
Ejemplo:

```js
function esPrimo1(numero) {
  var resultado;
  if (numero == 2 || numero == 3) resultado = true;
  else if (!(numero%2)) resultado = false;
  else {
    for (var i = 3; !!(numero%i) && i < Math.floor(Math.sqrt(numero)); i+=2);
    resultado = !!(numero%i);
  }
      return resultado;
}
for (let n=2 ; n<100 ; n++){
  if (esPrimo1(n)) console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: Frente a números grandes la raíz cuadrada es un gran rival para la mitad y supone un importante ahorro de poder computacional. Si quieren una demostración pueden tomar esta https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287203/how-would-one-prove-that-sqrtn-is-the-largest-divisor-that-needs-to-be-chec o buscar otra

Comment: Cierto, lo he explicado de la manera "fácil".

Comment: También es común hacer una rápida verificación para eliminar múltiplos de 3, y 5. Entonces en el for comienzas con el 7. También sumas de a 2 ya que no quieres pasar por los números pares de nuevo.

Comment: Claro. Pero no está demás decirlo para los que quieran más detalles.