# Numeros primos hasta cierto numero

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, números-primos

Tengo que realizar un script que me pida un numero y dado este numero calcular los números primos que hay desde el 0 hasta ese numero.

Por ahora tengo este código, pero no funciona como me gustaría

```js
let n1 = prompt('Ingrese un numero mayor que 0: ', '');
let primo;
for (let i = 2; i < n1; i++) {
    if (n1 % 2 == 0) {
        document.write(n1 + " es primo");
    } else {
        document.write(n1 + " no es primo")
    }
}
```

Comment: Más que un problema de JavaScript o de bucles, esto es un problema algorítmico. Antes de  sentarte a programarlo, investiga algunos [algoritmos para calcular números primos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_primo#Encontrar_n%C3%BAmeros_primos). Tu script solo revisa la división por 2, eso no es suficiente. 21 no es divisible por 2, pero no es primo...

Comment: Para otra vez, usa el buscador de preguntas, esto se ha respondido un montón de veces. Por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466349/divisores-y-n%c3%bameros-primos/466779#466779

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un número primo es aquel que sólo puede ser divido entre 1 y él mismo (sin que haya decimales y sin contar con el 1).

```js
// Pedir un número al usuario
let numero = prompt('Ingrese un numero mayor que 0: ', '');

// Comprobar cada uno de los números desde el 1 hasta `numero` para ver si son primos o no
for (let i = 2; i <= numero; i++) {

    let es_primo = true;

    // Dividir i entre 2 hasta (i - 1), si alguna de las divisiones no tiene resto, no es primo
    for (let f = 2; f < i; f++) {
        if (i % f == 0) es_primo = false;
    }

    if (es_primo) {
        document.write("El número " + i + " es primo.<br/>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En realidad es fácil. Vea este pseudocodigo

```
Algoritmo Primos
Escribir "Escribe un numero para saber los primos"
Leer numeroPrimos;

numeroComprobar<-2
numeroDivisor<-2
countPrimos<-0
esPrimo = Verdadero

Mientras countPrimos < numeroPrimos Hacer   
    
    Si numeroDivisor < numeroComprobar y numeroComprobar%numeroDivisor == 0 Entonces    
        esPrimo = Falso
    FinSi
    
    Si  numeroDivisor < numeroComprobar  y esPrimo
        numeroDivisor = numeroDivisor+1;
    SiNo
        Si esPrimo
            Escribir "Numero primo: ",numeroComprobar           
            countPrimos = countPrimos+1
        FinSi
        
        numeroDivisor = 2;  
        numeroComprobar = numeroComprobar+1;
        esPrimo = Verdadero
    Fin Si
Fin Mientras
FinAlgoritmo
```

Puede ser mejorado, puede ser. Pero este fue el que se me vino a la mente.