# ¿Por qué mi función da True en vez de False?

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y tengo un problema con una de las tareas que debo hacer. Es una función para saber si un número es primo o no. Lo que pasa es que al terminar de hacerla cuando paso un número que no es primo, me devuelve True cuando me tendría que devolver False. A continuación dejo el código que escribí, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

```
function esPrimo(numero) {
  if (numero<=1) {
    return false;
  }
  else if (numero % numero === 0 && numero % 1 === 0){
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: Cualquier número positivo cumplirá esta condición: `numero % numero === 0 && numero % 1 === 0` sea primo o no. Todo número dividido por si mismo o por 1 tiene resto cero.

Comment: tenes razon no me di cuenta gracias

Comment: Relacionado: [Números Primos JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98287/numeros-primos-en-javascript/327338#327338)

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver-lo correctamente podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
function esPrimo(Numero){
    // En Principio es true pero con los casos especiales puede ser false
    var Retorno = true;
    var x = 0;
    if (Numero == 0 || Numero == 1 || Numero == 4) { 
        Retorno = false; 
    }else{
        for ( x = 2; x < Numero / 2; x++) {
            if (Numero % x == 0) { Retorno = false; }
        }
    }
    return Retorno;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Debe de ser por la sintaxis de los else que estas haciendo, sin tocar los condicionales esto queda así:

```
function esPrimo(numero) {
 if (numero<=1) {
   return false;
 }else{ 
   if (numero % numero === 0 && numero % 1 === 0){
     return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
 }
}
```